# Firefox returns pages without http status code

Tags: http, firefox, webserver, iis-10, http-response-codes

I know, there were several questions about that but it seems like there are a ton of reasons for that and I still can't figure out what's wrong in my case.

We have a website on 2 cluster servers. Requests to these servers are routed by user IP (so each particular user is always routed to the same server). One of the servers works perfectly fine, whereas on the other there is this strange behavior. In Firefox there are no HTTP response codes for ANY webpage I'm navigating to. As you can see on the screenshot all "documents" have no response code whereas "subdocuments" do have 200. For this test, I visited several website pages. No Ajax, no nothing, just click on various links on a page. All other resources (CSS, JS, images) also correctly returned with 200 status.

What's more confusing is that the page is correctly displayed in the browser, so the connection is not lost/interrupted/timedout. Everything seems normal except no HTTP status code.

Moreover, it seems like "under the hood" Firefox actually makes 2 calls to the server every time (only shows it as 1 call with no response code in the Network tab).

Chrome, Opera and IE work fine. Server Response headers are exactly the same in all browsers (except that Firefox shows `"Response headers (0 Gb)"` for some reason).

Does anyone know what could be the cause?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Firefox Developer Network tab]

Comment: It might simply read from browser side cache, and therefore no status code from server side. You can analyze IIS log files to confirm, or use a tool like Wireshark on server side.

Comment: Try using another extension/plugin to view header info. Perhaps the one you are using is buggy

Comment: Can you provide additional details such as Firefox Version, OS Details, OS Version etc?

Answer (score 1):

We can check what is going on with a simple test:

In summary: no HTTP request is being made

If you look closely, these entries are coming with 0 for all timing measurements.

The headers are coming without a remote address, protocol version and status.

Ok, no requests, but the response is there -> cache

To validate the assumption that the tool is not telling you, explicitly, that it is from a cached file, one can go to the storage section of the inspector and clean up all data from that site. After doing that, one would see that all requests have a code. Disabling the cache is not enough. But after that experiment you can re-enable the cache to see the phenomenon again.

A very important piece of information that is a complement, is that if there is a request, there shall be a code. The lack of code, headers linked to the origin of the data and such, are a clue that points to caching. (I would rather have an explicit message telling me that, at least as explicit as in chrome)